# what can I do with generate S-function

Tags: simulink

Is there someone who generate s-function from simulink subsystem by right click->generate s-function ?
could you explain me how the generated code could be used ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will generate the C code equivalent of your subsystem. You can use this code in a S-function block ('User-defined Function/S-function').

The "generate" menu also automatically create a block visualy similar to you subsystem but encapsulating the S-function (with this C code). If you do 'look under mask' on this block you will see the S-function itself. This block if faster than the original one.

Comment: yes , I got the s-function, but is the generated c code usable ? what is the difference between generate s-function and build subsystem ?

Comment: The C code is usable inside another program (with the MEX S-function API). Have a look in Subsystem.c (if your subsystem is named "Subsystem"). 
What do you want to do with it ?

Comment: in fact the generated subsystem.c can be used directly in embedded systems ? I think there is no difference between C cod egenerated by s-function and those generated by Real time workshop embedded coder , right ?

Comment: in my case, my model is developped with ".m" code , as it is a complex model I have no time to rewrite all in .C, I want to convert ".m" to ".c" to implement it directly in microprocessor , what could you suggest ?

Comment: Yes, it's the same code as in TTW embedded coder. There are interface between RTW and some target, it depends on your hardware. 
Here is a list of fully supported target : http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/idelink/ug/bsmx0_l-1.html
Otherwise, you will have to write a little bit of interface code but the largest part of your code can be generated.

Comment: what do you mean by interface ?

Comment: ok, so I resume: I can generate C code by right clickon subsystem-<generate s-function then use the generated c code directly in embedded systems lime microctrollers.

Comment: Yes and so it's far simpler than recoding all in C.